# When should one use RequireJS?

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I have decided to start using RequireJS for projects and I am confused on when it is best to use RequireJS and when it is not.

For example, I have a small site that uses around 4-6 scripts on each page. I am currently concatenating all scripts into one minified script. Would it make sense to not do this and instead load them with RequireJS?

I understand using RequireJS for large web apps, but what I am in the air about is whether or not it makes sense for smaller sites as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I started using requirejs very recently.

One of the main advantages I have noticed is the clear separation of scopes - I had a habit of muddying the global scope at times.

Having clearly isolated `modules` and their dependencies explicitly listed makes for reusable and manageable code.

Also minification is handled simply with requirejs making the transition from dev code to production code simple.

I now try to make sure that all my javascript is modular no matter how small the project, I think this has been a wise decision.